# Formula from text value cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, offset

In an Excel spreadsheet I count the blank rows between two rows with values. I use the MATCH formula. Now I need to get the largest number into the `st` column.

[image: ![Part of spreadsheet]

I have a solution to get the row numbers (of the rows with cells) and create array as text (e.g. `=MAX(W"&N2&":W"&O2&")`.

I cannot get the value from cell AK to be a real formula. I do not want to go for VBA, this would make things too complicated.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX():

```
=MAX(INDEX(W:W,N2):INDEX(W:W,O2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Entirely different interpretation (based on screenshot), in Row2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(J2<>"",MAX(OFFSET(K2,,,L2)),"")
```